# Looking for a time travel story: choosing between Nazis and Communists, ending with becoming a terrorist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I'm trying to identify an SF short story. I'm pretty sure it was in an anthology. I read it in English and almost certainly before 2000, I would guess that it's fairly old.

I only remember parts of the plot: A man from the modern USA travels to the future(I don't recall how). The future is ruled by the Russians. He goes back in time to kill Lenin, then back to the future where the Nazis won and rule the world. He tries to change things again.
In the end, the only thing he can come up with to bring about the Communist future (because it's vastly better then the other option), is to go back to his own time and run a campaign of terror. It ends with a faux-historical entry about the (perhaps fascist?) terrorist who murdered many people at the end of the 20th century.

Comment: Sounds like the sequel to Kung Fury.